# Unable To import import StandardCopyOption

Tags: java, eclipse, java-io

I am Unable to import the "Path" Class and StandardCopyOption for Java Input/Output operations in Eclipse Neon

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
```

and

```
java.nio.file; // for 'Path' Class
```

I am Using Eclipse Neon and I have JRE 8 installed in my PC? So my question here is, Is it anything related to the JDK which I don't have installed in my PC? If yes then how can I fix this problem and if not then what is the resolution for importing these classes?

Comment: What does Eclipse think you have installed? Look in the Preferences in Java > Installed JREs

Comment: sir i just got to know that my Eclipse is using JRE 6 and nio package was included in JRE 7 now question is how can change the eclipse JRE version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Eclipse Preference look at the 'Java > Installed JREs' page. If your Java 8 is not shown there click 'Add...' and add the JRE.

Then in your Java projects open the project Properties and look at the 'Java Build Path' page. If necessary edit the 'JRE System Library' entry and choose the Java 8 JRE.